# Throw a custom error with response body in fetch call

Tags: javascript, error-handling, fetch

I would like to know how can I create a custom error handling where I would get the resolved response body and passed it to the custom error in fetch function. 
In my example I getting a validation errors on many fields in response body. This is the example:

```
class ValidationError extends Error {
  constructor(resBody, ...params) {
    super(...params);

    this.name = 'ValidationError';
    this.body = resBody.json();
  }
}
```

And this is the fetch function:

```
return fetch(
  `${this.formUrl(id)}/status`,
  {
    method: 'PATCH',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(jsonBody)
  })
  .then((res) => {
    if (res.ok) {
      return res.json();
    }
    if (res.status === 400) {
      throw new ValidationError(res.body);
    } else {
      throw new Error(`http failed: ${res.status} ${res.statusText}`);
    }
  });
```

Which I then use in my component:

```
  .then(() => {
      this.setState({navigateTo: '/'})
  }).catch(error => {
    this.setState({error});
  })
```

But, this fails since `res.body` is the `readableStream` at that point. How can I fix this so that I can set different `error types` based on `response status` in my `fetch` function, where I would be able to use the `resolved response body`?

Answer (score 1):

A late reply. But hope it helps others searching for the same question.

We need to check ***error.response.data*** to get the resolved ***response body*** in catch block.

Since res.status > 200 will immediately throw an Error in Promise.then, so we need to something in catch.

```
.catch(error => {
    if (error.response.status === 400) {
      console.log(error.response.data)
    } else {
      .....
    }
  })
```

There are still some methods to get the details inside the error.

1. error.name
2. error.message

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error